# Deep learning model with Keras don't give me correct predictions after saving the model in JSON

Tags: python, json, deep-learning, keras

I use Keras to make a deep learning model to mimic the XOR gate. So here the model:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import random


X_train = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]) 
Y_train = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]]) 
print(X_train , Y_train ) 

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=1)

scores = model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train) 
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))

print( model.predict(X_train)) 
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("xor.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

inp=np.empty((1,2))

while 1:
    inp[0,0]=random.randint(0,1)
    inp[0,1]= random.randint(0,1)
    prediction = model.predict_proba(inp)
    print(inp, '=', prediction)

    input('Press enter to continue: ')
```

It give me good accuracy : acc: 100.00%
and a good prediction :

```
[[ 0.00422836]
 [ 0.99482214]
 [ 0.99641317]
 [ 0.00683813]]
```

when I try some random input to the Xor model I get the correct answer:

```
[[ 1.  0.]] = [[ 0.99641317]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.99482214]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.99482214]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.99482214]] 
[[ 0.  0.]] = [[ 0.00422836]] 
[[ 1.  1.]] = [[ 0.00683812]] 
[[ 0.  0.]] = [[ 0.00422836]] 
[[ 1.  1.]] = [[ 0.00683812]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.99482214]]
```

So that part is working but when I save my model in a Json File I when I load it in another script:

```
import numpy as np
from modelnumba import pop_General_6e
from  numba import njit
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import model_from_json



json_file = open('xor.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

inp=np.empty((1,2))

while 1:
    inp[0,0]=random.randint(0,1)
    inp[0,1]= random.randint(0,1)
    prediction = loaded_model.predict_proba(inp)
    print(inp, '=', prediction)

    input('Press enter to continue: ')
```

I don't get correct prediction.

```
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.52390206]] 
[[ 0.  0.]] = [[ 0.5]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.52390206]] 
[[ 0.  0.]] = [[ 0.5]] 
[[ 1.  0.]] = [[ 0.38872629]] 
[[ 1.  1.]] = [[ 0.42139927]] 
[[ 1.  1.]] = [[ 0.42139927]] 
[[ 0.  1.]] = [[ 0.52390206]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving only the structure of the model. This does not include the weights you got from training the model. To quote Keras FAQ:

> If you only need to save the architecture of a model, and not its weights or its training configuration, you can do: `json_string = model.to_json()`

Alternatively, try doing `model.save(filepath)`. This will save both the model structure and the weights that you got from training the model into the file specified with `filepath`.

Comment: you right, I need to save the weights with `model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')`and then load those weights with `loaded_model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')`. Obviously my script couldn't work.